# Sifting through data to find number of people in a group

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Of the $240$ campers at a summer camp, $5/6$ could swim. If $1/3$ of the campers took climbing lessons, what was the least possible number of campers taking climbing lessons who could swim?

My Attempt:

There are $200$ people without abilities so $40$ people who can both swim and climb.

Is my attempt a good approach to solving the problem? What's a better approach?

Comment: What do you mean by "without abilities"?

Comment: @5xum "without abilities"- those who can neither climb nor swim.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your $200$ swimmers, you can have the $40$ non-swimmers taking climbing lessons, so $40$ people will take climbing lessons who can swim. Therefore, the answer to your question is less than or equal to $40$.

Can we prove that it is equal? Well, Out of the $80$ campers, at most $40$ will not be able to swim (since there are $40$ non-swimmers all together), meaning at least $40$ will be able to swim. So the answer to your question is greater or equal to $40$.

Conclusion: the answer is $40$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your total population $N$. So $N=240$ and $\frac{5}{6}$ of that that population can swim. That makes a total of:

$$\text{People who can swim}=\frac{5 \cdot 240}{6}=200$$

Then we also know that there is $40$ people who cannot swim.

One out of three campers took climbing, so the total number of people who took climbing is:

$$\text{People who took climbing}=\frac{240}{3}=80$$

The least possible number of campers taking climbing who could swim would be reached if all the campers who cannot swim joined the climbing lessons.

Then after they all joined climbing there would be:

$$80-40=40 \quad \text{Positions available in the climbing lessons}$$

So the minimum number of people who could swim and attend climbing lessons would be 40 people.

Comment: I don't understand :"The least possible number of campers taking climbing who could swim would be reached if all the campers who cannot swim joined the climbing lessons.

Comment: @Ben ou know that 80 people took climbing lessons (this is fixed), so the minimum the number of people who can swim and took climbing lessons would be reached if all the people who cannot swim joined the climbing lessons letting this way less places available for the people who can swim.

Answer (score 0):

There are $40$ non-swimmers and $80$ climbers. $80-40=40$.